# How far away should I plant new citrus tree?

Tags: citrus, soil-amendment

My two 12-year-old orange trees did not recover from the hard freeze in the Houston area earlier this year. I have given time for new growth and cut a couple branches to check for green wood. Nada. The trunks are starting to turn black.

I would really like to replace them with new citrus, possibly Satsuma.  How far from the site of the dead/removed tree should I plant the new ones? Is there anything I should do for the soil before planting new trees?